# Flutter uploading image to firebase storage then write it on firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am making a program where whenever user signup, they need to upload image to firebase storage and then all the login data and image url will be writen on firestore as soon as the image uploaded, this is my code :

```
void signUp(String _email, String _password, File image) async {
  await _auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)
      .then((result) async{
    await uploadImage(image).then((value) {
      _firestore.collection('users').doc(result.user.uid).set({
      'uid': result.user.uid,
      'email': result.user.email,
      'imageUrl' : value!=null?value:""
    });
    });

Future<String> uploadImage(File image) async{
    String fileName = p.basename(image.path);
    Reference storageRef = _fstorage.ref().child('upload/$fileName');
    UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(image);
    await uploadTask.whenComplete((){
      storageRef.getDownloadURL().then((imageUrl) { 
        return imageUrl!=null?imageUrl:"";
        });
    });
  }
```

The problem is the value of imageUrl writen on the firestore document is always empty, even though the image file is successfully uploaded, any advice will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Did you try to print the values after upload? Is it returning the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `uploadImage` isn't actually returning anything to the caller.  The return statement you have now just returns a value from the anonymous function passed to `whenComplete`.  It's not being propagated out of the top-level function.  Try printing the value of `value` to see what it actually contains before you write it.

It seems like you want to simply `await` the results of both `putFile` and `getDownloadURL` in sequence to get the URL, then return it.

```
  Future<String> uploadImage(File image) async{
    String fileName = p.basename(image.path);
    Reference storageRef = _fstorage.ref().child('upload/$fileName');
    await storageRef.putFile(image);
    return await storageRef.getDownloadURL()
  }
```

I also suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage/#file-uploads).

Answer (score 1):

```
Future<String> uploadItemImage(mFileImage) async {
    final Reference storageReference = 
       FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("Items");
  
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await 
      storageReference.child("product_$productId.jpg")
        .putFile(mFileImage);
    
    var downloadUrl = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    return downloadUrl;
}
```